# What is the amount of Delta-V required to enter lunar orbit following Trans-Lunar Injection?

Tags: astrodynamics

How much do you need to decelerate in order to be captured into a stable lunar orbit from a [Trans-Lunar Ejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-lunar_injection) or TLI-type trajectory?

Comment: Are you asking about the minimum needed for lunar capture, or more typical insertions into low lunar orbit?

Comment: I suspect the theoretical minimum may be zero.

Comment: The minimum won't be zero, because there's no third body to provide a braking assist to change the almost-parabolic trajectory into ellipse, but the difference between these is minimal; with the transfer maneuver performed perfectly, it would be infinitesimal; with the error common to this type of maneuvers - a couple meters per second.

Comment: It’s zero; the sun’s influence can be used.

Comment: Let me put it this way - assuming you could be put onto a lunar flyby by piggybacking on a probe, like the 4M mission did, what would be the minimum needed to enter orbit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the minimum ∆v is zero: from a [ballistic capture trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_capture), marginally stable lunar orbits at about 20,000 km altitude can be reached for zero or nearly-zero ∆v cost; an orbiter can then descend to a lower orbit at leisure using low-thrust high-efficiency ion engines. More generally, [low energy transfers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_transfer) allow a tradeoff between travel time and insertion ∆v.

From an Earth-Moon Hohmann transfer, it takes about 680 m/s to reach a low lunar orbit at ~100 km altitude.

The Apollo missions started from a faster transfer orbit, so they required a little more ∆v; Apollo 11's initial LOI burn was [889 m/s to enter a 113 km pericynthion, 313.4 km apocynthion orbit](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/11day4-loi1.html).